# Android layout development

Tags: android, layout

I would like to develop a layout below. I am really confuse related to that. I used RelativeLayout, FrameLayout to develop this. But I am not getting perfect output. As per below image, the Dark Gray color is overlap the light Gray layout. If I used Relative layout then dark Gray will be in the light Gray area. And if I used FrameLayout then the other controls of light Gray will not set perfectly.

Please guide me the right path. I am stuck in this layout. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I would use a RelativeLayout with a TextView (?), a ListView (?) and then all the other Views. All properly **related** to the parent and/or to the preceeding View.

Comment: Is your light gray area a ListView or a collection?

Comment: No light view area is not a ListView. Its contain TextView, Buttons, ImageView etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to your figure, If all widgets need to show without scrolling vertically , you can have vertical linear-layout here,

1. TextView
2. Button,
3. ImageView
4. List view with defined height
5. Other widgets